# unresolved name rand::thread_rng

Tags: rust

I wanted to use some random numbers for a benchmark:

```
#![feature(test)]

/// benchmarks for different map implementation
extern crate test;
extern crate rand;

use test::Bencher;
use rand::Rng;

#[bench]
fn setup_random_hashmap(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut val : u32 = 0;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut map = std::collections::HashMap::new();

    b.iter(|| { map.insert(rng.gen::<u32>(), val); val += 1; })
}
```

However, rustc comes back with:

```
bench.rs:14:16: 14:32 error: unresolved name `rand::thread_rng`
bench.rs:14     let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
```

thread_rng is defined in `rand` as a `pub fn`. What declaration am I missing? I am using `1.2.0-nightly (8f9f2fe97 2015-06-07)`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using nightly? [This](http://is.gd/S7X1yu) code works for me. I've just added `#[feature(rand)]` and everything compiled exactly as you provided.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I don't think `#[bench]` methods are compiled in the playpen. http://is.gd/el8M4f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can reproduce this in Rust 1.0 (and at least up through 1.13):

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    rand::thread_rng();
}
```

With the same error:

```
error[E0425]: unresolved name `rand::thread_rng`
 --> <anon>:4:5
  |
4 |     rand::thread_rng();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unresolved name
```

To fix this, you need to add the `rand` crate to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "*"
```

This is due to the fact that [Rust has an internal, hidden crate also called `rand`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/7b0f2af27f18b6c81fe6a2faab0ba96e0da3bba5/src/librand). When the 1.0 stability guarantees were looming, many of these mostly-internal crates were spun out to [their own repos](https://github.com/rust-lang/rand) and [hosted on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/rand). However, the compiler still needed parts of these crates, and so stubs of them were left in the compiler, but marked private.

> could I just use a different rng then?

A clever idea that appears to work! For future people, this **only** applies to nightly builds, and that means you accept whatever breaking code might happen!

```
#![feature(rand)]

extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::IsaacRng::new_unseeded();
    println!("{}", rng.gen_range(0, 10));
}
```

The biggest downside is that every run of the program will have the same sequence of numbers, because it will always have the same seed. This may be a benefit for benchmarking though!

Comment: Do I need to use cargo to build then? Because this was just a small benchmark, I tried to use rustc directly.

Comment: @llogiq You can always link to a crate by hand, doing everything that Cargo would do ^_^. I don't know for sure that there's no way to access the built-in random functionality, but [my first attempt failed](http://is.gd/NJdvBt). I have found it pretty easy to spin up one-off Cargo projects, so that's the direction I would recommend.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the reason for the error because the author explicitly specified that nightly compiler is used (and nightlies can use external crates freely, albeit with feature annotation).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev check my [attempt to use the crate in a nightly](http://is.gd/NJdvBt). The function [`thread_rng` is in a private module](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/621a10e7f32d790c39a0b4528369cf7959dd7d34/src/libstd/rand/mod.rs#L159), not just feature-gated. Also, "external crates" is a bit misleading - I'd suggest that "external crates" are those from crates.io, not those secretly bundled with the compiler ;-).

Comment: @Shepmaster could I just use a different rng then?

Comment: Funny, I just ran into this exact same issue… I was expecting the error to be "missing crate 'rand'" but it was entirely unexpected!